# Get all users with a specific email domain using Microsoft Graph SDKs

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I would like to make this query to the Microsoft Graph API using the Microsoft Graph SDKs. I would like to get all users with the domain in email address is @something.com.

Use of $filter with the endsWith operator

```
GET ../users?$count=true&$filter=endsWith(mail,'@something.com')
```

I tried this following line of code :

```
var users= await _graphServiceClient.Users.Request().Filter("mail '@something.com'").Select(u => new {
                u.Mail,
                u.DisplayName,
            }).GetAsync();
```

The error I get is :

```
    Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: BadRequest
Message: Invalid filter clause
```

Without the filter, it works fine. Am I missing something?

Refs:
Advanced query : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters
Microsoft Graph SDKs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=CS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `$count` query parameter you need to add the `ConsistencyLevel` header with `eventual` value.

```
GET /users?$count=true&$filter=endsWith(mail,'@something.com')
ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

In C# specify header option and query option for the request:

```
var options = new List<Option>();
options.Add(new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual"));
options.Add(new QueryOption("$count", "true"));
```

add `endsWith` operator to a filter.

```
var users = await _graphServiceClient.Users
    .Request(options)
    .Filter("endsWith(mail,'@something.com')")
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Could you just add the QueryOption("$count", "true") in the options to your answer and as you said the filtering endsWith only works with $count query parameter. Your answer resolved my problem! I will close this question once you added the query option :) Thank you a lot

Comment: @JulienTurcotte Answer updated with $count query parameter.